# Binomial basis and Narayana numbers

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to expand a polynomial in binomial basis to standard basis, $L(t) = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^{n + 1}h_i^*\binom{t +d - i}{d}, d= 2n +4, h_i^* = N(n+2, i+1)$ the Narayana numbers. I suspect that $L(t) = \frac{1}{c_n}(t+n+3)(t+n+2)^2\cdots (t+2)^2(t+1)$ for some integer $c_n$ and tried $$[t^i]L(t) = \frac{1}{d!}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^d(\sum\limits_{l = i}^d s(d, l)\binom{l}{i}(d-k)^{l-i})N(n+2, k+1) $$ where $s(d,l)$ is the signed Stirling number of the first kind, but I can't simplify this, any help will be appreciated.